# How to secure and navigate between child routes?

Tags: angular, location, angular-router

I have the following `route` structure in my `Angular` app:

```js
path: ':piva/:negozio',
component: NegozioComponent,
children: [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ModuliComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'location',
    component: LocationComponent
  },
  {
    path: ':type',
    component: ProductsComponent, 
    //I can access this only if 'location' is true
  },
  {
     path: 'item/:id',
     component: ItemComponent,
  },
];
```

So I have to access path **`:type`** only if in **`location`** the .get request returns `true`, in location page there is an input box which check if the position of the client is in range of the shop which makes deliveries, if it's in the range I have to `redirect` the user to `:type`.

So I was trying to make the following in my `location.component` on submit:

```js
getLocation(): void {
  this.locationService
  .inRange(
    this.addressComponent.geometry.location.lat(),
    this.addressComponent.geometry.location.lng()
   )
  .subscribe((data: any) => {
    if (data.inRange) {
      this.router.navigate([
        'asporto',
        { relativeTo: this.activatedRoute },
      ]);
    }
  });
}
```

But when I try to submit the `button` I get the following error in the console:

```sh
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'asporto; relativeTo = Route%28url: 'location', %20path:' location'%29'
```

Comment: I would recommend that you have a global AuthGuard class and then use it with the 'canActivate' property on the route declaration. Plus you have not declared the path 'asporto' in your routing module..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this issue, you should use a `CanActivate` `Guard` on your `:type` path and use the `locationService` inside that. So do something like this:

**app.route.ts**

```js
path: ':piva/:negozio',
component: NegozioComponent,
children: [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ModuliComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'location',
    component: LocationComponent
  },
  {
    path: ':type',
    component: ProductsComponent, 
    canActivate: [locationGuard]
  },
  {
     path: 'item/:id',
     component: ItemComponent,
  },
];
```

**location-guard.service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { LocationService } from './location.service';

@Injectable()
export class LocationGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(public locationService: LocationService, public router: Router) {}
  canActivate(): boolean {
    this.locationService.inRange(
      this.addressComponent.geometry.location.lat(),
      this.addressComponent.geometry.location.lng()
     .subscribe((data: any) => {
       if (data.inRange) {
         this.router.navigate([`/type`]);
         return ture;
       }
       return false;
     });
  }
}
```

Comment: didn't know about AuthGuard, actually i solved by almost your solution, but instead of using locationService in AuthGuard i'm checking for location cookie in LocationGuardService, thank you!